# Does def in clojure save the return value of a function or will the function get evaluated each time?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I define a function

```
(defn func [a] a)
```

Then I define

```
(def funcUsage (func 5))
```

If I now use funcUsage twice, does the function func get called twice or is the return value stored into funcUsage?
I.e

```
(println funcUsage)
(println funcUsage)
```

Would that be equivalent to

```
(println (func 5))
(println (func 5))
```

?
It seems like that in my program. Does def store the value of an evaluated function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you evaluate `(def funcUsage (func 5))`, `func` is called once and value `5` is bound to symbol `funcUsage`.

When you evaluate

```
(println funcUsage)
(println funcUsage)
```

you only print value of symbol, `func` is not called again. So, these calls:

```
(println funcUsage)
(println funcUsage)
```

(`func` is not called) and

```
(println (func 5))
(println (func 5))
```

(`func` is called twice) are not equivalent.

You can also test it, if you add some side effect for `func` like this: `(defn func [a] (println "I am called...") a)` or `(defn func [a] (Thread/sleep 1000) a)`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the def is evaluated each time the namespace is loaded and that will happen in situations like AOT compiling when building an uberjar. Having def expressions that contain side-effects is therefore a very bad idea but for simple, pure computations like this it's "OK".

Answer (score 0):

The `def` form creates a Clojure `Var`.  Each `Var` is like a global variable that points to a value. In your case, `(func 5)` will be called once and the result is saved in the Var `funcUsage`.

You can find more information in this [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation). Be sure to see the Clojure CheatSheet and the books Brave Clojure and Getting Clojure.